# Split string to array, remove empty spaces

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, split

I have a question about splitting string. I want to split string, but when in string see chars "" then don't split and remove empty spaces.

My String:

```
String tmp = "abc 123 \"Edk k3\" String;";
```

Result:

```
1: abc
2: 123
3: Edkk3  // don't split after "" and remove empty spaces
4: String
```

My code for result, but I don't know how to remove empty spaces in ""

```
var tmpList = tmp.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) return new[] { s };
                    return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                }).ToList();
```

Or but this doesn't see "", so it splits everything

```
string[] tmpList = tmp.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ';', '\"', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add .Replace(" ","")

```
String tmp = @"abc 123 ""Edk k3"" String;";
var tmpList = tmp.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
{
    if (i % 2 == 1) return new[] { s.Replace(" ", "") };
    return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.Split` is not suitable for what you want to do, as you can't tell it to ignore what is in the `"`.

I wouldn't go with `Regex` either, as this can get complicated and memory intensive (for long strings).

Implement your own parser - using a state machine to track whether you are within a quoted portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. Instead of splitting, specify what you want to keep.

Example:

```
string tmp = "abc 123 \"Edk k3\" String;";

MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(tmp, @"""(.*?)""|([^ ]+)");

foreach (Match s in m) {
  Console.WriteLine(s.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ", "") + s.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
abc
123
Edkk3
String;
```